# Is the browser extension storage persistent?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

The browsers have the eviction policy.

It means that the browser can automatically delete site's data (`LocalStorage`, `IndexedDB`, ...) in some cases.

[This eviction policy does not apply to installed PWAs that have been added to the home screen.](https://web.dev/storage-for-the-web/#eviction)

But that about web extensions? Does this policy apply to them? Are `browser.storage.local`, `LocalStorage`, `IndexedDB` persistent in the web extensions?

Comment: AFAIK they are excluded just like PWAs.

Comment: I'm not sure about WebStorage and IndexedDB in respect of extensions, most likely that policy takes the same effect. But I'm certain it can't be applicable to `chrome.storage` (as well as `browser.storage`) which has its own policy called [throttling limits](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#limits).